# Hibernate illegal attempt to dereference collection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

hey everyone i have a spring boot app am trying  execute a query but am getting this error

```
illegal attempt to dereference collection [dev0_."IdDev".vehid] with element property reference [marque] [SELECT DISTINCT d FROM com.ardia.MDValidation.entities.Dev d Left Join d.validationdvd v WHERE d.etatdev.id = 6 AND d.vehid.marque.Nommarque= ?]
```

here's my Dev Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"DEV\"")
public class Dev {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@JsonView(View.databymaj.class)
@Column(name="\"IdDev\"")
private int id ;

@JsonView(View.databymaj.class)
@Column(name="\"NomDev\"")
private String nomdev;

@Column(name="\"NomDLL\"")
private String dll ;


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="\"IdEtatDev\"")
private EtatDev etatdev ;

@JsonView(View.databymaj.class)
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="\"IdEcu\"")
private Ecu ecu ; 


@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="\"VEH_BY_DEV\""
        ,joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="\"IdDev\"")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="\"GRPMOD\"")})


private Set<Vehid> vehid = new HashSet<>();




@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="\"IdMaj\"")
private Maj maj ; 


@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="\"FCT_BY_DEV\""
                    ,joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="\"IdDev\"")}, 
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="\"IdFonction\"")})
private Set<Fonction> fonction = new HashSet<>();

@JsonView(View.databymaj.class)
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="dev")
private Set<ValidationDVD> validationdvd =new HashSet<> () ;
```

here's my Vehid class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Vehid\"")
public class Vehid {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="\"CODE_VEH\"")
private int idv ;
@JsonView(View.model.class)
@Column(name="\"NOMVEH\"")
private String model ;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="\"IdMarque\"")
private Marque marque ;
```

and finaly the Marque class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Marque\"")
public class Marque {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="\"CODMAR\"")
private  int id ;
@JsonView(View.marqonly.class)
@Column(name="\"NOMMAR\"")
private String Nommarque ;
```

am trying to execute this query

```
  @Query(value="SELECT DISTINCT d FROM Dev d Left Join d.validationdvd v WHERE d.etatdev.id = 6 AND d.vehid.marque.Nommarque= ?")
  public List getbymarkalldata(String mark);
```

but it not seem to work and  actually it make sens how it doesn't work because am trying to access a list of `<vehid>` like this `d.vehid` but how can i access to the attribute any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Solution just like he say's another Join was missing here's the syntax

```
@Query(value="SELECT DISTINCT d FROM Dev d Left Join d.validationdvd v JOIN d.vehid vs  WHERE d.etatdev.id = 6 AND vs.marque.Nommarque= ?")
 public List getbymarkalldata(String mark);
```

Comment: please accept my answer then ... or your answer if you wish ;-) ... it may help others

Answer (score 5):

The problem is here : `AND d.vehid.marque.Nommarque= ?`
In your Dev class, vehid is a collection ... you cannot reference it in a query that way ... you have to use `JOIN` keyword ... 
Just like what you did with validationdvd : `Left Join d.validationdvd v`

`Left Join`or not, is up to you to decide ...